# Suppressing pivot items in a pivot chart

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a pivot table that lists the number of visitors to a store on a given date. There are 3 columns of data, the date column and two columns of numbers representing the visitors. When I create a chart from this data I get a bar of data that represents dates before and after the range of dates that make up the data. I can suppress all dates that occur prior to the dates I want to view by using the command:

```
With Worksheets("Pivot Tables").PivotTables("Weekly Statistics").PivotFields("Date")
    .PivotItems.Item(1).Visible = False
```

However, I can't find a way to suppress the dates that occur after today's date. This leaves me with a column on my bar chart that is blank and has the axis value ">3/27/2013". I can suppress it by actually typing this line:

```
    .PivotItems.Item(">3/27/2013").Visible = False
```

but having to manually do this every time I update the sheet is laborious and makes the sheet unusable to anyone else.
I tried to create a variable that would update the value inside the () but I can't get it to work.

```
     Dim t
     t = Worksheets("Data").Range("i3").Value   
     .PivotItems.Item(t).Visible = False
```

(where `i3` is a cell in the `Worksheet("Data")` that is a concatenation of the date; in this case the cell contents are `">3/27/2013"` )

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use alternative filtering technique:

```
t="3/27/2013"
Worksheets("Pivot Tables").PivotTables("Weekly Statistics").PivotFields("Date").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlBefore, Value1:=t
```

However, it is used as of Excel 2007.

If not working try to start with:

```
    Worksheets("Pivot Tables").PivotTables("Weekly Statistics").PivotFields("Date").ClearAllFilters
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  The date filter is properly applied with your code but the pivot table still lists a pivot item that is >3/27/2013.

Comment: My fault, I wasn't precise enough. The answer is improved now.